# Unmarshal from a arraylist in java

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, unmarshalling

Hy,

I have a list of objects inserted into an ArrayList by a HashMap

```
 private static Map<Integer, Users> usersH = new HashMap<Integer, Users>();  

     static {  
         ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList();
        UserImpl u = new UserImpl();
        users = u.getUsers();
        //int j = users.size();

         for(int i=0; i<users.size(); ++i){
             Users u1 = new Users();
             u1.setUserID(users.get(i).getUserID());
             u1.setUserName(users.get(i).getUserName());
             u1.setUserPass(users.get(i).getUserPass());
             u1.setUserRight(users.get(i).getUserRight());
             usersH.put(users.get(i).getUserID(), u1);
            // System.out.println(usersH.toString());
         }


     }
```

my Rest service brings me the right info with the following addnotation

```
@GET
    @Path("/listareF")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public static UsersList listme(){
        UsersList ul = new UsersList();
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Users> utiliz : usersH.entrySet()){
           // m = new HashMap();
            m.put(utiliz.getKey(), utiliz.getValue());
            //ul.setVariabila();

        }
        ul.setVariabila(m);
        return ul;

    }
```

the JAXB:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//@XmlRootElement(name ="USER")
public class Users {

    private int userID;
    private String userName;
    private String userPass;
    private String userRight;

    public Users(int uI, String uN, String uP, String uR) {
        this.userID = uI;
        this.userName = uN;
        this.userPass = uP;
        this.userRight = uR;
    }

    public Users() {

    }

    public Users(int uI) {
        this.userID = uI;
    }

    @XmlElement  
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    @XmlElement 
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @XmlElement  
    public String getUserPass() {
        return userPass;
    }

    public void setUserPass(String userPass) {
        this.userPass = userPass;
    }

    @XmlElement  
    public String getUserRight() {
        return userRight;
    }

    public void setUserRight(String userRight) {
        this.userRight = userRight;
    }
```

The Java class containing the root element:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class UsersList {


ArrayList<Users> variabila;

public UsersList() {

}

/*public List<Users> getVariabila() {
    return variabila;
}*/

public void setVariabila(HashMap<Integer,Users> collection) {
    this.variabila = new ArrayList(collection.values());
}
@XmlElement(name="getusers")
public ArrayList<Users> getUsers() {
            return variabila;
        }



    }
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><usersList><getusers><userID>1</userID><userName>maracineanu</userName><userPass>12345</userPass><userRight>u</userRight></getusers></usersList>
```

The unmarshaller:

```
    StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(output);

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UsersList.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(output);
    System.out.println(output);
   // UsersList ul = new UsersList();

    HashMap<Integer,Users> ul2 = (HashMap<Integer, Users>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    System.out.println(ul2);
```

and I get the error on the line with the code: HashMap ul2 = (HashMap) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

I have tried also: UsersList ul2 =(UsersList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
But the same error occurs.

How output is created:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/Pictori/rest/weby/listareF");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //conn.
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        System.out.println("Content type:" + conn.getContentType());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output=br.readLine();

//      while (output != null) {
//          output = br.readLine();
//      }

        System.out.println(output);

        StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(output);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.addToPack(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Scope.add(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty$ReceiverImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)

Please help me,

Sincerely,

Comment: Need the code to show how 'output' is created/defined.

Comment: I added the code u asked for.

Comment: What in the world are trying to accomplish with your `setVariabila`. Once you call that method, you lose all your map keys. How in the world do you expect to magically cast to a map, when a map no long exists. If you want the map, then why don't you have the field in the user list be a map? Why do you convert it to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was on my wrapper class. I was wrapping into an ArrayList and iwas using an Map.

Solution bellow:

```
    @XmlRootElement
public class UsersList {


Map<Integer,Users> variabila;

public UsersList() {

}


public void setVariabila(HashMap<Integer,Users> collection) {
    this.variabila = new ArrayList(collection.values());
}
@XmlElement(name="getusers")
public ArrayList<Users> getUsers() {
            return variabila;
        }



    }
```